# Uso de vírgula em oração subordinada

Tags: sintaxe, pontuação, frases, orações-subordinadas

Seria preciso usar vírgula antes de `quando`?

> "Ainda tentava acalmar o animal quando espreitou algo em seu
>   encalço."

Comment: Quando a frase está na ordem direta, a vírgula é facultativa nas orações subordinadas adverbiais [temporais].

Comment: Obrigado, Valdeir.

Answer (score 1):

Quando a frase está na ordem direta, a vírgula é facultativa nas orações subordinadas adverbiais [temporais], esta regra vale também para os advérbios e locuções adverbiais.

> **Atenção!** Ordem direta é quando a frase segue a seguinte sequência: *Sujeito* + *Verbo* + *Complemento* + *Adjunto Adverbial*, por exemplo.

Caso a oração adverbial esteja intercalada, o uso é obrigatório:

> "Ainda tentava, quando espreitou algo em seu encalço, acalmar o animal."

No início da frase, utiliza-se — em regra — a vírgula, no entanto há gramáticos que defendem que o uso é obrigatório somente em orações extensas (mais de 3 palavras) e facultativa em orações curtas (até 3 palavras)

> "*Quando¹ espreitou² algo³ em⁴ seu⁵ encalço⁶*, ainda tentava acalmar o animal." Extensa = Uso obrigatório da vírgula
>
> "*Quando¹ espreitou² algo³* ainda tentava acalmar o animal." = Curta = Uso facultativo da vírgula